# Novel featuring anosmia and protagonist with a missing arm

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to recall a science fiction novel I read (in English, in the US) in the 1980s (probably). Somewhat post-apocalyptic; most people are anosmic (unable to smell) due to some past plague (I think). There is a plot point having to do with one of the characters who *can* smell (but is concealing that fact), and a booby-trap involving a toilet and smelly substances (sorry if that's a spoiler).

The (male) protagonist was missing an arm for some reason; there was a passage in the book where he comments on the convenience of not having to figure out where to put your arm when you're sharing a bed with your lover ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*[Telempath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telempath)* by Spider Robinson

> The novel's protagonist, Isham Stone, is on a mission to kill the man allegedly responsible for the destruction of civilization: a scientist named Wendell Carlson, currently living alone at the former Columbia University in what used to be New York City.
>
> Isham has been told by his father, scientist Jacob Stone, that Carlson is a madman who brought the world to its current state by releasing a "hyperosmic plague": a virus that increases the sensitivity of the human sense of smell by many hundred times. With their senses of smell thus heightened, humans were unable to tolerate the odors produced by their own pollution-producing technology; the result was mass insanity and widespread rioting.

....

> Isham sets out for New York and succeeds in locating Carlson. He learns from Carlson, however, that the man actually responsible for developing and releasing the plague is Isham's father Jacob. Isham returns to his home colony and sets a trap to kill his father, then returns to New York.

It's actually a matter of that most people can smell too well, which meant a large amount of humanity perished from people driven crazy by all the smells around them. Isham believes that his father can't smell, which was how he survived the plague. His father can smell, which is how he avoids the ammonia trap.

And yes, according to the blurb, his arm is gangrenous at the start of the book and rereading it, Carlson amputates it after Isham collapses in front of them. I couldn't find your quote in a quick skim of the book, but Isham does have a fair amount of dark humor in his internal monologue. Personally, the quote that stuck out to me, was that later in the book, he attempts to fight off some people with "the strength of a virtuous man", and then comments that that's not much stronger than anyone else as he's overwhelmed.

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: There aren't many books about people sense of smell.

Comment: Hella fine book, BTW, as is everything Robinson has published.