# Science fiction story about a chemical that super-increased the sense of smell

Tags: story-identification

The story is about a chemical that extremely heightened the sense of smell and as a result many people died. Life is impossible without the use of nose-plugs. The hero found out that a person intentionally caused it and goes to kill him.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Telempath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telempath)* by Spider Robinson as per [Novel featuring anosmia and protagonist with a missing arm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268138/novel-featuring-anosmia-and-protagonist-with-a-missing-arm/268139#268139)

> The novel's protagonist, Isham Stone, is on a mission to kill the man allegedly responsible for the destruction of civilization: a scientist named Wendell Carlson, currently living alone at the former Columbia University in what used to be New York City.
>
> Isham has been told by his father, scientist Jacob Stone, that Carlson is a madman who brought the world to its current state by releasing a "hyperosmic plague": a virus that increases the sensitivity of the human sense of smell by many hundred times. With their senses of smell thus heightened, humans were unable to tolerate the odors produced by their own pollution-producing technology; the result was mass insanity and widespread rioting.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes this is the story. You, Sir, are a genius.

Comment: @NilanjanBasak: Don't forget to click on the checkmark